# iOS/Obj-C UIScrollView views not being added properly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am attempting to make a basic scroll view with a connected page control, and I have run into some problems with my code. My viewDidLoad method looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog (@"View did load");
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;

NSArray *frames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
for (int i = 0; i < frames.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.backgroundColor = [frames objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    NSLog (@"Looped, i = %i color = %@", i, [frames objectAtIndex:i]);
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * frames.count, scrollView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"The width is: %f", self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
}
```

The problem seems to be that the coloured frames I attempt to add to the view never appear (not even the first one). If I didn't have ARC enabled, I would have released the CGRect frame at the end of each loop, but it really should do that itself with ARC, right?

When I run the app, both in the simulator and on my actual phone, I get a black screen with the UIPageControl dots at the bottom. When I swipe my finger across the ScrollView nothing happens, but if I pull it very far to one side, the pageControl moves to the next "dot".

The last NSLog sentence always outputs 0.0000, indicating that none of the views have been added to the scroll view.

All help is very appreciated :)

Comment: can you show us where you have initialised the scrollview? is the nib file setting it up correctly? Can you log the value of self.scrollView?

Comment: From the header:
(at)property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    From the implementation:
(at)synthesize scrollView;
    The scrollView is connected to the property in the header in Interface Builder, and I am using storyboard. As far as I can see, there is no errors in the storyboard view containing the scrollView. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is doing it in viewDidLoad. Move your code to viewDidAppear: and it should work fine. Frames are not yet set in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Wow thanks a bunch! That immediately solved my problem! Kudos :)

Comment: May I ask you an additional question, @rdelmar ? If I wish to put three different view controllers in those views instead of the blank pages with different colours -- how would I achieve that?

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold, that gets a little more complicated. You would need to add them as childViewControllers of the viewController that contains the scroll view. You should read Apple's docs on custom container controllers to get an idea of how you work with them.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the docs then. Again thanks a lot for your help!